# is there a way in R to hash password in data frame from MySQL?

Tags: r, hash

I am relatively new to R language and I'm facing difficulty doing hash password. The one that I,ve done only manage to hash the first column. I want to hash each column respectively.

```
library(pool)
library(RMySQL)

sqlname <- "SELECT userName FROM staff "
sqlname <-data.frame(dbGetQuery(pool, sqlname))

sqlpassword <- "SELECT password FROM staff"
sqlpassword <-data.frame(dbGetQuery(pool, sqlpassword))

user_base <- data_frame(
 user = (sqlname),
 password = (sqlpassword), 
 password_hash = sapply((sqlpassword), sodium::password_store),
 permissions = c("admin", "standard"),
 name = c("User One", "User Two")
)

View(user_base)
```

Here what I,ve got

```
user1
123456
$7$C6..../....eo0MryfxLoInICi3RRGLBj48UCJD4XtGCbdUb7JhnO/$i/gw1MWGfD8Ri7l5l/Nvx.qUhvRTlKHWVssuiD4MV85
admin
User One

user2
147852
$7$C6..../....eo0MryfxLoInICi3RRGLBj48UCJD4XtGCbdUb7JhnO/$i/gw1MWGfD8Ri7l5l/Nvx.qUhvRTlKHWVssuiD4MV85
standard
User Two
```

The hash password should be different from my understanding but I fail to do it. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `data.frame` you are building from query result as column in your final expression.

A `data.frame` is a list of columns. `data.frame` function when given a list of columns (this is what happens when you provide `user=(sqluser)`) is able to cope with and will handle this a individual columns in the final `data.frame` (that is user will get the single column in `sqluser`). The problem is in your call to `sapply((sqlpassword), ...)` that will not iterate on individual passwords but on columns of `sqlpassword data.frame`) which combined with the fact that when provided a vector of string, `sodium::password_store` will return a single value. Not what you expect !

so the better code is

```
user_base <- data.frame(
  user = (sqlname$userName),
  password = (sqlpassword$password), 
  password_hash = sapply((sqlpassword$password), sodium::password_store),
  permissions = c("admin", "standard"),
  name = c("User One", "User Two")
)
```

The way you retrieve username and password is also a bit convoluted. You could get them in a single query

```
sqluser <- "SELECT userName, password FROM staff"
sqluser <-data.frame(dbGetQuery(pool, sqluser ))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your explanation really gave me insight about RMySQL. May the force be with you.